# How to add a trendline to a time series line chart without casting error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a trendline to my output plot. My dataframe looks something likes this:

```
Years   Percentage increase
2021    1.480378
2022    1.270628
2023    0.42773
2024    2.271726
2025    3.857106
2026    2.123221
2027    2.658651
2028    2.786197
2029    2.106992
2030    2.959151
```

I'm trying to use the following code to get the trendline:

```
plt.plot(df['Years'], df['Percentage increase'])
x=df['Years']
y=df['Percentage increase']
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
pylab.plot(x,p(x),"r--")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

*UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'lstsq_n' input 1 from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'*

Can anyone help me out on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have python objects stored in your DataFrame rather than floats, which numpy doesn't know how to handle. I can't say which elements in your DataFrame are objects, but you could either change how you constrct the DataFrame to ensure everything is a float, or cast elements to floats before the polyfit command. Your code should work fine if both `df['Years']` and `df['Percentage increase']` return lists of numbers